# Skype Telephone number Formatting in browser

Tags: skype-for-web

How do I turn off the Telephone number formatting in the browser window.

Comment: What website is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to deactivate or uninstall the Skype Add-on.
In newer versions there is also the option to just turn the highlighting off in the settings of the Add-on.

Here is a link to the Skype FAQ:
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA657/How-do-I-use-Skype-Click-to-Call

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know, but I found I can just switch of the feature by clicking on the Skype Icon, top right in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase any developers out there are wondering who to stop this form mucking up there pages, or design, you could try and insert some hidden code, for example:

```
<span style="display:none;">_</span>
```

Example:

```
01234 <span style="display:none;">_</span> 123123
```

Comment: Not exactly what Turismo asked but nice tip to any web developer out there.

Comment: I know, I found this question looking for the answer, so thought I would share once I found a solution...

Comment: I also found a page where Skype explains how to format numbers so that the Add-on recognizes them. This of course also helps developers to figure out what to do to the numbers so the won't be recognized anymore: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12006/How-do-I-script-webpages-to-find-phone-numbers-using-Click-to-Call